# Raster map Northing Easting conversion

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, google-maps, google-earth, latitude-longitude

I have a raster map which shows a place near **Olympic dam,Australia**. On the top and right border it has some Northing and Easting values **58550E & 35400N** I really dont know how to locate this place. Any idea?

I have tried it in Google earth,arcmap,Qgis platform's default conversion options but not found exact location.
I tried few websites like
http://www.ga.gov.au/geodesy/datums/redfearn_grid_to_geo.jsp
but couldn't get result

X = 58450E
  Y =  35400N

**Update:** I have found that 5 numbers in grid denotes last 5 digits of xy coordinates,So I have to some values for xy as prefix. I tried adding some values and got some result.But I don't feel it is an exact result.Still looking for answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olympic Dam is in MGA (UTM) zone 53. Try [X=658450 Y=6635400](http://www.ga.gov.au/bin/geodesy/run/gda_redfearn?geo_grid=0&Name=&easting=658450&northing=6635400&zone=53&Submit=Submit+Data) (Latitude:     -30 ° 24 ' 10.90280 ''      Longitude:  136 ° 38 ' 58.03372 '')